# Unable to save new record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, controller, record

I have created a new model, "tools", which will be used to create records of equipment that will later be attached to relevant projects. To begin however I need to create a record for each of the tools. I have created all the necessary pages as I have done with similar models however when I attempt to save a record I am redirected to my Root page, an indication that the record did not save. As I am not getting an error message it is hard for me to tell where the problem lies.

New Form

```
<%= form_with model: @tool, local: true do |form| %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :name, :class => "form-component-header" %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit :class => "form_button" %>
  </p>

  <% end %>

  <% Tool.find_each do |tool| %>
    <%= tool.name %>
    <%= link_to 'Delete Tag', tools_path(@tool),
              method: :destroy,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <% end %>
```

Controller

```
class ToolsController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_search

def new
    @tool = Tool.new
end

def create
    tool = Tool.create(tool_params)
    if tool.save
        redirect_to tools_path
    else
        redirect_to 'root'
    end
end

def destroy
    @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
    @tool.destroy

    redirect_to tools_path
end

private
    def tool_params
        params.require(:tool).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Model

```
class CreateTools < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :tools do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: try `tool.save!`, you might know what the problem is

Comment: You call Tool.create, which should save it for you. I think you want Tool.new there, instead, followed by your if/save

Comment: Neither of these seem to work. I don't believe it is an issue with the wording here as I have several other forms with the same syntax that work properly.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `@tool` in the create action?

Comment: Where is ur set search methode

Comment: I had based the controller above on this previously successful model so using @tool vs tool doesn't seem to make a difference. def create
     tag = Tag.create(tag_params)
     if tag.save
        redirect_to tags_path
     else
        redirect_to tags_path
     end
   end

Comment: The set search method is used to set auto parameters for a search function present on each page. It does not have any effect on unrelated functions but need to be present to prevent a search related error from being thrown at each page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tool.save! I was able to find the issue. As I had intended the record to belong to both a user and a project I needed to set up an intermediary model to handle this relationship. By basing this model on a previous model with a sole 1:many relationship, I was not accounting for this more complex relationship which was not allowing the record to save.